# Connecting to Java server through HTML Phonegap client

Tags: java, html, phonegap

My university task is to create a mobile phone application using phonegap (Html and css to mobile application) however I'm trying to take this further.
I want to create a game similar to the old zynga mafia wars (not on the same scale but in terms of concept, not planning to release this, just a university project).

I'm trying to figure out in terms of a client and external server, how I'd connect and send data from html to java and back.

I guess the question I'm really asking is how do I press a button in html, make it send certain data/parameters to a java server, allow it to do calculations, and then return the outcome of those calculations back to the html client to refresh the application?

Ps. I've not actually used phonegap before, and I'm not sure why this is a task for my course, but I've been told I HAVE to use phonegap for this. So I'm trying to branch out to not only do this more in a programming language I prefer (aka. Java), but so I can have networking as it's 1 of the advanced features and I need to include at least 1.

Thank you in advance for any help,
Ayden.